# ionic run android not work

Tags: android, ionic-framework

```
C:\Users\mortadha\android-apps\todo2>ionic run --debug android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\mortadha\android-ap
ps\todo2\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\mortadha\android
-apps\todo2
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\mortadha\android-ap
ps\todo2\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js C:\Users\mortadha
\android-apps\todo2
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
No target specified, deploying to device '4d00e9048f4f4043'.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build
-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Total time: 13.391 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\mortadha\android
-apps\todo2\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\mortadha\android
-apps\todo2\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemo
n=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: this happens when your compileSdkVersion  and buildToolVersion doesn't matches like you have set version 22 and using  buildToolVersion 21

Comment: how i can out them in the same version

Comment: check out your build gradle file and manifest file